# handle HPDF_FAILD_TO_ALLOC_MEM during creation of pdf file

Tags: c++, libharu

I am using libharu library for creating pdf and getting following into system

```
hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0 which HPDF_FAILD_TO_ALLOC_MEM
```

My query may I know the reason behind this error. and application got crash. is there way to handle this error as I am not able generate pdf

```
**Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4117, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4177, detail_no=0
***Error: hPDF error error_no=4133, detail_no=0
***Error: (Report::NextPage) current page is empty
***Fatal: *************************** FATAL ERROR ***************************


***Fatal: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x35270) [0x7ffff6801270]
***Fatal: HPDF_Page_SetWidth+0x49 [0x596159]
```

I have tried to written small program and try to reproduce this issue but did not encounter any error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "hpdf.h"
using namespace std;

class Report {
    public:
    HPDF_Doc document;
    HPDF_Page currentpage;
    void static error_handler (HPDF_STATUS,HPDF_STATUS,void *);
    void NextPage();
    Report(string, string, int);
    ~Report();
    string m_ReportFilePath;
};

void Report::NextPage()
{
    if (document == NULL)
    cerr << "(Report::NextPage) document is empty" << endl;

    currentpage = HPDF_AddPage(document);
    if (currentpage == NULL)
    cerr << "(Report::NextPage) current page is empty" << endl;
    cout<<currentpage<<"  "<<std::endl;
    HPDF_Page_SetWidth(currentpage, 595.3);
}

Report::Report(string fileName, string booktitle, int marg) {
    m_ReportFilePath = fileName;
    document = HPDF_New(Report::error_handler, &document);
    NextPage();         // Create new page
}

Report::~Report()
{
}

void Report::error_handler(HPDF_STATUS error_no,
               HPDF_STATUS detail_no, void *user_data)
{
    cout << "hPDF error error_no=" << (HPDF_UINT) error_no <<
    ", detail_no=" << (HPDF_UINT) detail_no << endl;
}

int main() {

    Report r("test.pdf", "test", 50);
    return 0;
}
```

compile command

> `/depot/gcc-4.8.2/bin/g++ -rdynamic -Wall -I../include -std=c++11 -c lib_haru.cpp -o lib_haru -L../libs -lhpdf`
> `/depot/gcc-4.8.2/bin/g++ -o libh lib_haru.o -rdynamic -L../libs -lm -ltcl8.4 -lxml2 -lz -lpng -lhpdf -lncurses -lreadline -Wl,-rpath,/depot/gcc-4.8.2/lib64`

```
OBJECTS=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC)))
VERSION=$(USER)
CXXFLAGS=-g -D Version=$(VERSION) -rdynamic  -Wall -I../include
LDFLAGS=-rdynamic -L../libs -lm -ltcl8.4 -lxml2 -lz -lpng -lhpdf -lncurses -lreadline -Wl,-rpath,/depot/gcc-4.8.2/lib64 
#CXX= /usr/bin/g++
CXX= /depot/gcc-4.8.2/bin/g++
```

issue when I compile on this machine

```
Linux Machine 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

GDB output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6852c31 in __strlen_sse2 () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

Possible issue

```
currentpage = HPDF_AddPage(document);
if (currentpage == NULL)
logerror << "(Report::NextPage) current page is empty" << endl;
#value of currentpage is 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've seen this error was when the PDF became so large it consumed all available memory. In my case, I was creating images using the PDF primitives (like a filled rectangle).

You really haven't given enough information to help diagnose the problem. Version of libHaru, 32 or 64 bit, generally what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for input @Bill H,  lib_haru : 2.0.7 and gcc is 4.8.2  one strange thing, if I compile on Linux machine than I get else not

Comment: issue machine : Linux machine 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1  working machine : Linux machine 2.6.32-754.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1

Comment: Bill H, How may i know it is 64 bit or 32 bit libharu version

Comment: perfect suggestion it was bit issue download new library and did not face any issue

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to written small program and try to reproduce this issue but did not encounter any error.

I suggest you need to make the small program bigger until you can reproduce the problem, if still not clear post the code so we could investigate and comment.